# embedded tomcat not working on spring boot 2.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I'm a newbie to the Spring Boot. So Today I started working on Spring Boot 2.0.1 Version. But when I run the Spring Boot application it will not load the embedded tomcat. I'm using Spring Boot Hello world example taken from Spring Boot reference documentation. My Tomcat version was 9, and Java version is 10.0.1.

I'm running the Spring boot in the following way:

1. start.spring.io and Click on the Generate Project on "MAVEN" with "JAVA" and Spring Boot "2.0.1"
2. Group "com.globomatics" and artifact "bike"
3. Dependencies "web"
4. After that, I click on the "Switch To full version" tab
5. And changing the Java version 8 to 10
6. Finally "Click on the Generate Project"
7. Import maven existing project...

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.globomatics</groupId>
    <artifactId>bike</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bike</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**under src/main/java/BikeApplicaton.java**

```
    package com.globomatics.bike;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class BikeApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
     String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BikeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and running the application as "Java Application" and it gives the output in the following way:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-05-07 12:06:18.348  INFO 3640 --- [           main] com.globomatics.bike.BikeApplication     : Starting BikeApplication on siva-PC with PID 3640 (started by siva in E:\Udemy Course Ae\SPRING WITH SPRING BOOT AT LYNDA\demo)
2018-05-07 12:06:18.352  INFO 3640 --- [           main] com.globomatics.bike.BikeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-07 12:06:18.412  INFO 3640 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5e21e98f: startup date [Mon May 07 12:06:18 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-07 12:06:18.593  INFO 3640 --- [           main] com.globomatics.bike.BikeApplication     : Started BikeApplication in 0.715 seconds (JVM running for 1.434)
2018-05-07 12:06:18.598  INFO 3640 --- [       Thread-0] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5e21e98f: startup date [Mon May 07 12:06:18 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

Comment: DO you mind posting your pom/gradle file?

Comment: Add your `pom.xml` and you might want to purge your local repository in case you have a bad jar. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` this will remove all dependencies a rebuild will redownload the dependencies (`mvn package` or a refresh in your IDE).

Comment: i added my pom.xml here. and i already redownloaded the jars. but still it showing the same error msg

Comment: M. Deinum's comment should be an answer.  Purging my local repo fixed this problem for me.